# How can I see the contents of SQLite DB during Debug on iOS

Tags: sqlite, nativescript

How can I view the contents of an SQLite DB on iOS during debug. I run tns debug iOS, use chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/inspector.html?experiments=true&ws=localhost:41000 to debug the app. In other development environments I have used, I have been able to view the SQLite data via WEB SQL or similar in debug, but not in Nativescript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could copy the SQLite DB file into any application that can decode it. I usually use https://sqlitebrowser.org/

If you are running on Simulator, you could simply log the path to application data directory, if you navigate to that path you should find the SQLite DB and simply drag and drop into the sqlite browser application to view data.

If you are using real device, you could set `UIFileSharingEnabled` to `true` on your `info.plist` which should enable you to copy any file within documents directory when connected to iTunes.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the heads up. A somewhat convoluted method but I'll give it a go. Thanks